# $y=\frac{(\sin x)^{101}}{\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi}\right\rfloor+\frac{1}{2}}$ is an even function

Tags: functions

> Prove that $$y=\frac{(\sin x)^{101}}{\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi}\right\rfloor+\frac{1}{2}}$$ is an even function.

I tried this problem in desmos.com and could see that it is an even function but not able to prove it.

Comment: Hint: break the function into smaller parts and show whether each is even or odd

Comment: It is generally accepted here that you give some indication of what techniques you have tried (other than putting it into an online software!) and if you truly do not know where to begin, giving details of techniques you have learnt about is helpful in allowing users to give an answer at a level which you will understand. For starters, for this question you could give the definition of 'even function' as you understand it and how you have been taught to decide if a function is even

Comment: @Yanko The function is zero for $x=\pi$ and $x=-\pi$.

Comment: @kccu oh yes. For some reason I thought that $\sin(\pi)=1$.

Comment: **Hint:** Show that, on $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$, $\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac12$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you know that $\sin(x)$ is odd, so $\sin(x)^{101}$ is odd, i.e., $\sin(-x)^{101}=-\sin(x)^{101}$. So it's enough to prove the denominator is also odd, i.e.,
$$\left\lfloor \frac{-x}{\pi}\right\rfloor + \frac{1}{2}=-\left(\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi}\right\rfloor+\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
This is actually not quite true, but it's true for $x$ not equal to an integer multiple of $\pi$. To show this, suppose that $k$ is an integer such that $k < \frac{-x}{\pi} < k+1$. Use this to determine the values of $\left\lfloor\frac{-x}{\pi}\right\rfloor$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi}\right\rfloor$ and go from there.

To deal with the case when $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, note that the numerator is always zero in this case, so it doesn't matter what the denominator is.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: compute
$$
\lfloor t\rfloor+\lfloor -t\rfloor
$$